# how to plot straight lines per point in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.gca()

ax.plot_date(dates, df['y'])

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(
    matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=matplotlib.dates.SA, interval=2)
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%a %d\n%b %Y'))
```

which gives[image]

but i'd like each point to be a straight line. I'm not bothered about the y value of the line, but it should fill the plot area top to bottom.

How to proceed?

Comment: Take a look at vlines (for vertival lines) in the matplotlib module.

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen, please expand your comment into an answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using vertival lines from the `matplotlib` library like this.

```
from matplotlib import pylab

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
dates = range(10)
ax.vlines(dates, ymin=-1, ymax=1.5, color='r')
pylab.show()
```

I added some more or less random arguments to the function. More can be added like other plotting functions in `matplotlib`.